# Redux Saga Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I'm still learning about `redux-saga` but stuck at 2 problem.

Here is my code:

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/ssuhat/12333a6196f7ade7b022927a7bb2fdff)

The problem is:

1. `Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions`
2. Function doSignIn keep getting call even though the action never call. Action is can be call by button click.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

A few problems I see:

```
function* rootSaga() {
    yield [
        takeLatest(actions.authRequest, doSignIn),
    ];
}
```

[takeLatest](https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/docs/api/index.html#takelatestpattern-saga-args) first argument is a "pattern" to match on, not an action. So you really want something like:

```
takeLatest(AUTH_REQUEST, doSignIn)
```

From [take pattern param docs](https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/docs/api/index.html#takepattern):

> If it is a String, the action is matched if action.type === pattern (e.g. take(INCREMENT_ASYNC)

For problem 1, `Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions`, never pass a function to `put`. Your doSignIn saga should look more like

```
export function* doSignIn() {
    try {
        yield put(actions.sendingRequest());

        const { email, password } = yield put(actions.authRequest());
```

You do the put effect correctly later in the saga, so just make sure to always do that.

I'm not 100% sure on the problem with number 2. See if the above suggestions help.

Answer (score 0):

re: Part 2 of your question:

You haven't given any button code but a common failing is how a function is assigned to a button.

`onPress={this.function()}` triggers without being pressed.

`onPress={this.function}` triggers when pressed.

`onPress={() => {this.function()}}` triggers when pressed.